# Cakephp How to use $components = array('Security') correctly

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I can't understand what is happening.
I just want to call PostsController.index() but It doesn't work.

```
// View/Posts/index.ctp
<?php echo $this->Form->create(false, array('type' => 'post')); ?>
```

If I comment out this at PostsController.

```
// public $components = array('Security');
```

**Environment :**
Cakephp 2.3.8
PHP Version 5.4.7

**Updated:**
It is enough to be able to use Csrf check, so I modified 'Security' options like below.

```
public $components = array(
    'Security' => array('validatePost' => false),
);
```

But I still don't understand SecurityComponent behavior...

Answer (score 1):

1. passing "false" as first parameter is not a good idea. There should be a model name like:

   echo $this->Form->create('Post', array('type' => 'post'));
2. If you want custom action use 'url' parameter:like:

   echo $this->Form->create('Post', array('type' => 'post', 'url'=>array('controller'=>'Post', 'action'=>'add'));

Comment: You don't need to pass false in any case. Simply leaving out the value will have the same effect.

Comment: @Nik Chankov Thanks. But the problem seems $components = array('Security'); I updated the question. sorry ;)